# Sed a line and replace it with content in the line

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have millions of line that looks something like this. I am looking for a way to replace these lines with what the "TABLENAME" is. "TABLENAME" can be different everytime. "TABLENAME" is always in this line. Basically I'm looking to convert this path to just the "TABLENAME". My idea was to look for the 5th occurence of " " and replace the whole line of it with sed. Does sed have this ability ? Thank you in advance.

My line

```
    path : /BLAH/BLAH1[(@name="BLAH2")]/BLAH/BLAH[(@BLAH="SERVER")]/BLAH[(@name="CHECK")]/sampler[(@name="SAMPLE")][(@type="")]/table[(@name="TABLENAME")]/rows/row[(@name="AROW")]/cell[(@column="ACELL")]
```

The result I want ( Turn My line to just the line below ) ( I can not use sed replace path to TABLENAME because sometimes it may be a different table name and i don't know which one it may be)

```
TABLENAME
```

Originally I can use

```
sed -r "s/.*table\[\(@name=\"([A-Z]+).*/\1/" myfile
```

to do this as suggest by another stackoverflower but it looks like it doesn't work because of the extra 8 spacing before path. If I remove the 8 spacing this code is going to work but because of the way I'm calling this in java these spaces are always going to be there. Is there a work around to this command ?

Comment: Preceding spaces shouldn't be your problem as they will be matched greedily by the first .* in the pattern. So this regex should work as intended.

Comment: Can table names contain lower-case letters, digits, underscores, any other special characters?  Your regex assumes only upper-case letters; maybe `[^"]+` would serve you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if table[(@name="TABLENAME")] will be present only once in each line, you can use:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)table/table/g' | cut -d ")" -f 1 | cut -d "=" -f 2
```

Output:

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ echo "/BLAH/BLAH1[(@name="BLAH2")]/BLAH/BLAH[(@BLAH="SERVER")]/BLAH[(@name="CHECK")]/sampler[(@name="SAMPLE")][(@type="")]/table[(@name="TABLENAME")]/rows/row[(@name="AROW")]/cell[(@column="ACELL")]" | sed 's/\(.*\)table/table/g' | cut -d ")" -f 1 | cut -d "=" -f 2
TABLENAME
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$
```

In the example i am just echoing the string and processing. If processed from a file (i.e the string in file), output would be "TABLENAME".

```
sed 's/\(.*\)table/table/g' | cut -d ")" -f 1 | cut -d "=" -f 2 | sed 's/"//g'
```

Comment: Working as intended . really creative method of a quick fix to my problem.